# Using that $L_2(\mathbb{R})$ is a Hilbert space, show that $L_r^2(\mathbb{R})$ is a Hilbert space.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

The exercise is as follows:
Using that $L_2(\mathbb{R})$ is a Hilbert space, show that $L_r^2(\mathbb{R})$ is a Hilbert space when equipped with the inner product:
$$\langle f,g\rangle_{L_r^2(\mathbb{R})} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\overline{g(x)}r(x)\;dx.$$
The vector space is defined as $L_r^2(\mathbb{R}):=\{f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow\mathbb{C}\bigg|\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)|^2r(x)\;dx < \infty\}$, and the continuous function $r:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow ]0,\infty[$.

I have already shown that it defines an inner product on $L_r^2(\mathbb{R})$.
I have shown that the inner product is well-defined by:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)\overline{g(x)}r(x)|\;dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)\overline{g(x)}|r(x)\;dx \leq \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)|^2r(x)\;dx\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\overline{g(x)}|^2r(x)\;dx\right)^{1/2} =  ||f||_{L_r^2(\mathbb{R})}||\overline{g}||_{L_r^2(\mathbb{R})} =||f||_{L_r^2(\mathbb{R})}||g||_{L_r^2(\mathbb{R})} < \infty.$$
First equality is done by $r$ being positive $(r:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow ]0,\infty[)$ and first inequality is done by Cauchy-Schwarz' inquality.

My question is; how do I show that $L_r^2(\mathbb{R})$ is a Hilbert space using that $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is a Hilbert space?

Comment: In which book can I find this problem?

Comment: I think it is from "Functions, Spaces, and Expansions" by Ole Christensen. It was used as the main material of our course. I do not remember the exact problem.

Comment: oh thanks!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(f_n)$ is Cauchy sequence in $L^{2}_r(\mathbb R)$  then $f_n {\sqrt r}$ is Cauchy in $L^{2}(\mathbb R)$. If this sequence converges to $g$ in $L^{2}(\mathbb R)$ then $f_n \to g/ \sqrt r $ in $L^{2}_r(\mathbb R)$: $\int |f_n(x)-\frac {g(x)} {\sqrt {r(x)}}|^{2}r(x)dx=\int |f_n(x)\sqrt {r(x)}-g(x)|^{2}dx \to 0$.

Comment: Can you expand this maybe? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: e.g. how does this show that $L_r^2(\mathbb{R})$ is a Hilbert space? Also, how do you know that $f_n\sqrt{r}$ is a Cauchy sequence in  $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ based on $(f_n)$ being a Cauchy sequence in $L_r^2(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: @osi41 It is  a Hilbert space because it is a complete inner product space.  The norm in $L^{2}_r(\mathbb R)$ given by $\|f\|_r=\sqrt {\int |f(x)|^{2}r(x)dx}$. So $\|f_n-f_m\|_r =\sqrt {\int |f_n(x)-f_m(x)|^{2}r(x)dx}=\sqrt {\int |f_n(x){\sqrt r(x)}-f_m(x){\sqrt r(x)}|^{2}dx} \to 0$ etc.

Comment: Okay thanks, that makes sence! So now I need to show that $f_n \rightarrow f\sqrt{r}$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ in $L_r^2(\mathbb{R})$, which then shows that $L_r^2(\mathbb{R})$ is a complete inner product space, hence a Hilbert space?@KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: To show that $f_n \to f/ \sqrt r $ in $L^{2}_r(\mathbb R)$ write down the norm square of $f_n - f/ \sqrt r $ in $L^{2}_r(\mathbb R)$. @osi41

Comment: Then I would get: $||f\sqrt{r}-f_n||_{L_r^2(\mathbb{R})}^2 = \int |f(x)\sqrt{r(x)}-f_n(x)|^2 r(x)\; dx = \int |f(x)r(x)-f_n(x)\sqrt{r(x)}|^2\; dx$, but then what? I can't see why $f_n \rightarrow f/\sqrt{f}$ in $L_r^2(\mathbb{R}).$ Can you further explain @KaviRamaMurthy ?

Comment: @osi41 I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The function $\sigma : L^2_r (\mathbb{R} )\to L^2 (\mathbb{R} )$, $\sigma (f) =f\sqrt{r} $ satisfies $$\left<f,g\right>_{L^2_r (\mathbb{R})} =\left<\sigma (f),\sigma (g)\right>_{L^2 (\mathbb{R})} $$ hence it is an isometry.
So now you can use a fact that isometry between metric spaces preserves completeness.